# Cannot Read numpy From libpgm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, importerror, ubuntu-16.04

I installed libpgm1.3. The documentation of libpgm1.1 is here: http://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/index.html (I could not find any documentation of 1.3). Then executed the code below.

```
import numpy
import libpgm
import libpgm.pgmlearner
```

The console gave me an error message.

```
File "test_libpgm.py", line 3, in <module>
    import libpgm.pgmlearner
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/libpgm/pgmlearner.py", line 35
    raise ImportError, "numpy is not installed on your system."
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This means the code can import numpy in line 1, but failed in line 3. I checked pgmlearner.py here:

```
32: try:
33:     import numpy as np
34: except ImportError:
35:     raise ImportError, "numpy is not installed on your system."
```

Why cannot this import numpy? Could anyone solve this problem?
I use python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You should install `numpy`

Comment: numpy is not installed try the following command to install.
`pip install numpy`

Comment: `Note that numpy, scipy, and Python 2.7 are required for this library.` - You are using it with python3.5. See http://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/index.html

Comment: Thank you! I missed the sentence, Python 2.7 is required... It is working now