# ImportError: numpy is not installed on your system

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a new programmer with python. I'm using python 3.5 in a 64-bit windows.
I was installed libpgm module but when i type `from libpgm.pgmlearner import PGMLearner` i got this error:

`ImportError, "numpy is not installed on your system."`

Then i install numpy using pip. Now when i type `import numpy`i don't get any error but when i type `from libpgm.pgmlearner import PGMLearner` i get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from libpgm.pgmlearner import PGMLearner
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\libpgm\pgmlearner.py", line 35
    raise ImportError, "numpy is not installed on your system."`

Is there every one who can help me?...Thanks.

Comment: Do you have multiple Python environments installed on your machine?

Comment: see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765410/cannot-read-numpy-from-libpgm) - you likely have python 2.7 and 3.5 installed

Comment: @fahi see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200137/installing-numpy-on-64bit-windows-7-with-python-2-7-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the library to work, `"Python 2.7"` , `numpy` and `scipy`,are required,, unfortunately you are using `Python 3.5`

Go through [`libpgm docs`](http://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to install numpy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy):

Get the right one for you system, so it would be:
numpy‑1.12.0b1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

It should download a .whl file. Once the download is complete, open the downloads folder. Open command prompt and go to the downloads folder. If you don't know how to do that I would recommend learning the command prompt. But anyway here is how you would

```
cd Downloads
```

Then run

```
pip install numpy‑1.12.0b1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```